# Error: No such device grub rescue (error appears when booting from USB too)

Tags: boot, live-usb, asus, grubrescue

I know this error appears many times on the web, and the advice is to boot from a live CD/USB and re-install the grub from the terminal. This is not a solution for me since I am getting the error when booting from USB.

From the BIOS I have set the boot device priority to 'Removable Device'. Not sure if I should set USB to 1st Hard Disk.

```
error: no such device: 8d0615a7-b8ff-499f-88e0-99b323b9d524.
grub rescue>
```

PC: ASUS EeePC 4G.

Trying to install Lubuntu 13.04

Comment: The error means that your hard-drive (device: 8d0615a7-b8ff-499f-88e0-99b323b9d524) is not being found. If this a new install it likely means that the `fstab` file was not created correctly.  If it just started happening on a previously working install, then unless you just recently changed something(like updated) then it *may* mean your HD is failing.  Please include more info:  Is this a new install?  If this is an old install Did you change anything in the system, just before this started happening?

Comment: I'm also confused by: "From the BIOS I have set the boot device priority to rem dev. Not sure if I should set USB to 1st Hard Disk"  have you selected the USB as the first boot device?  Not sure what "rem dev" is... What do you mean by "Not sure if I should set USB to 1st Hard Disk"  You should try to boot the USB by selecting it in the boot menu or by telling the BIOS to boot from it first.  You should then be able to boot into the liveUSB and try to fix your grub from there.

Comment: I have set the boot device to removable device/usb. Booting from usb gives me the grub error too, that is what I tried to initially explain. I have taken the Asus out of storage and do not remember what the last actions were that I made.

Comment: If you are getting the **exact** same error with the USB then the USB is not being recognized by the system, otherwise the UUID number would be different.  UUID is Unique Universal Identifying Device.  The USB and the HD would not have the same number.  It is possible that the USB is bad, try it in another computer if possible. If the USB is good then this is beyond my ability, all the ways I know to fix this need to be done from a LiveUSB.  It is possible to manually load grub from the prompt but I don't know how...

Comment: The USB is good, I have also tried other removable devices. "1st Hard Disk" In the BIOS under Boot > Hardisk Drives There is the option to set 1st/2nd Drives. Default is: 1st drive set to HDD. I tried: 1st drive set to USB. The install got some of the way and then stalled. Not sure if that is of any help?

Comment: Well if you got it to boot to the USB then I understand the "1st HD" part of your question, ASUS must have some strange BIOS options that I have never seen hence the confusion.  By the install started but then stalled, do you mean that you booted into the USB then selected "Install Ubuntu", the installer started, then it stalled? or that it started to boot then stalled(I assume the prior just making sure) At what point did Ubiquity(the installer) fail?  Also, use the "Try Ubuntu" and see if you can see and browse your hard drive, it will show up in nautilus as a XXGB Volume in the left pane.

Comment: On install I was able to select language, but then it seemed to skip the drive option/partitioning part and I actually got to the desktop screen (without menu bar etc.). As it did not do anything I killed it. I am now trying (Lubuntu) and it is stalling on Lubuntu loading screen.

Comment: Not sure about Lubuntu but the desktop can take a little bit of time to appear when you use the "Try Ubuntu".  The background will appear but the panel and launcher will take a bit.  You may have given up too early, you could try again and wait a bit, however if Lubuntu does not want to load either, you may have a hardware problem, and that is beyond me, I *might* be able to narrow down the problem if I actually had it but trying to picture what you are doing then explain what you need to do is beyond my ability. One of the downfalls of these kinds of help site, if the helper is no expert.

Comment: I hate to give you the "it might be a hardware issue so your on your own" answer that you get form most tech support lines when they are in a hurry to get rid of you.  Like I said above I'm just not expert enough to help you beyond this, even if I could figure out what you might need to do, I would have a hard time trying to explain it in a way that mad any sense.  I'm like a deaf guy trying to explain to a blind guy what the color red looks like.